# Laravel, getting uploaded file's url

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm currently working on a Laravel 5.5 project, where I **want** to **upload files**, **and** then, I want to **get their url back** of the file (I have to use it client side).

now my code looks like this:

```
public function pdfUploader(Request $request)
{
  Log::debug('pdfUploader is called. ' . $request);
  if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) {
    $extension = $request->file->extension();
    $fileName = 'tmp' . round(microtime(true) * 1000) . '.' . $extension;
    $path = $request->file->storeAs('temp', $fileName);
    return ['status' => 'OK', 'path' => URL::asset($path)];
  }
  return ['status' => 'NOT_SAVED'];
}
```

It works fine, I **got back the OK status, and the path, but** when I want to use the path, **I got HTTP 404**. I checked, the file is uploaded fine..

My thought is, I should register the new url in the routes. If I have to, how can I do it dynamically, and if its not necessary what is wrong with my function?

Thx the answers in advance.

Comment: make sure your saving somewhere in public if you want to use as asset.  I have an import folder I use for that. $file->move(base_path() . '/public/import/', 'uploadedfile');

Comment: What does the path look like? I think you've probably uploaded it somewhere that's not available correctly.

Comment: The answer below shows me the problem, I uploaded the files the storage/app/temp and I had to move it to the public app. :)

Comment: Now official documentation suggests to create a [symbolic link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default laravel store all uploaded files into storage directory, for example if you call `$request->file->storeAs('temp', 'file.txt');` laravel will create `temp` folder in `storage/app/` and put your file there:

```
$request->file->storeAs('temp', 'file.txt'); => storage/app/temp/file.txt
$request->file->storeAs('public', 'file.txt'); => storage/app/public/file.txt
```

However, if you want to make your uploaded files accessible from the web, there are 2 ways to do that:

**Move your uploaded file into the public directory**

```
$request->file->move(public_path('temp'), $fileName); // => public/temp/file.txt
URL::asset('temp/'.$fileName); // http://example.com/temp/file.txt
```

**NOTE**: make sure that your web server has permissions to write to the public directory

**Create a symbolic link from storage directory to public directory**

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command will create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`, in this case we can store our files into `storage/app/public` and make them accessible from the web via symlinks:

```
$request->file->storeAs('public', $fileName); // => storage/app/public/file.txt
URL::asset('storage/'.$fileName); // => http://example.com/stoage/file.txt
```

Comment: Ohh thanks for the long answer. I could do it, with your guide! I had to move to the public path, and after then made a symbolic link, and its working. Thx again!