# Cannot access laravel project via url http://localhost/myproject/public/

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

When I ran php artisan serve then copy this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Its works. I want to access my project via url http://localhost/myproject/public/.
It returns blank page. And when I inspect the element it returns 500. Internal server error. Appreciate your help regarding this. Thank you.

Laravel version: 5.4

Php Version: 7.1.12

[image]

I can access the folders but when accessing the public folder itself. Returns blank page.

[image]

When run the php artisan serve. Its working

[image]

Comment: can you try accessing other pages, different routes and see if its working or not.

Comment: please be more detailed. show us your home page route.

Comment: I can access the folder but the files. Returns 500. Internal server error

Comment: I add some screen shots for easily understanding

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. It's the PHP version. Php7.0 does not support it

Answer (score 0):

**You can try doing:**

```
composer install
```

**Or  In the root of your project try to run**

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

Comment: Still can be access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ not http://localhost/myproject/public/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442410/5349795) of my prev. question. You should set symbolic link as the [docs said](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk).